# Angular JS : Service : Flip the page on adding more divs/sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have 6 widgets in one page1.I want to flip the page1 to Page2 when the 7th widget is added to it. For adding the widget i am using the Angular JS.

**The solution for the same problem you may also suggest in javascript or jQuery.**

My **recordsService.js** is as following :

```
app.service('recordsService', function () {
this.getRecords = function () {
    return records;
};

this.insertRecord = function (newWidgets) {
    records.push(neWWidgets);
};


this.getRecord = function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        if (records[i].id === id) {
            return records[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

**& recordcontrollers.js is as follwing:**

```
 app.controller('RecordsController', function ($scope, recordsService) {

init(); 
function init() {
    $scope.records = recordsService.getRecords();
}   
$scope.insertRecord = function (type) {

    if(type=="tag")
        {

    var newWidgets =
    {
        "id": 7,
        "age" : "7"
     };  
        recordsService.insertRecord(newWidgets);
  }
        };

  });
```

Here is the picture that what i really want to need. here 5 divs are visible when someone click on link1 6th will be added to the next page so only next page will be visible with the new 6th div only.[image]

Looking for help.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav! What do you mean by page1 to page2? Do you want to direct to another url? A js fiddle will be helpful to understand your problem better.

Comment: @SelvamPalanimalai: Page1 & Page2 are the part of data-ng-view so url must be same only i need is to flip the view part (with same url).The code is much complex thats why not able to create fiddle.

Comment: ng-view is used with routes. So if you dont want to change the url, you can use ng-show and ng-hide. Is the view in seperate html files? or are they divs?

Comment: view is separate HTML file with name record-list.html. ng-show & ng-hide fine but they used only to show and hide the div's not to flip the view part when someone added more divs to it.

Comment: ok. So you have external html files which need to load into view and be shown when a widget is added. If I got this right, then you need to use ngInclude directive.

Comment: ngInclude fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment. You can bind this with the action of addition of a new widget. ( You can watch the variable containing the widget list. Onchange it will automatically trigger page change)

Comment: @SelvamPalanimalai:yes that is fine on Page1 i have 6 divs on Page2 i have 6 divs. when i am using ng-include the entire page1 replaced with page2. that is i achieved by pagination concept also. but i want to add 7th widget on click and want to add flip the page and need only page2 with the 1 div that is 7th.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30471/discussion-between-selvam-palanimalai-and-vaibhav-jain)